# Remove Correalted Subquery with Not Equal Join

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, mysql-workbench, correlated-subquery

SELECT
(SELECT COUNT(0)
FROM `TestTable` `s_t`
WHERE `s_t`.`Test_type_id` <> `t`.`Test_type_id`
) AS count
FROM
`TestTable` `t`

This is taking time eventhough index exists on table.
Help needed in removing correlated scalar subquery or removing <> for performnce

Tried using left join, but didnt work
Created covering index , but didnt work

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please [edit] your question to show us what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, for each `Test_type_id`, you want to know how many rows of the table do **not** have that id. But that's a guess.

How to get that, efficiently:

First, make an aggregate subquery to find the number of rows of each type.

```sql
          SELECT COUNT(*) num, Test_type_id
            FROM TestTable
           GROUP BY Test_type_id
```

Then use the subquery in your JOIN. [Fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/FpLG-O0g).

```sql
SELECT num.Test_type_id,
       SUM(num.num) num_different
  FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT Test_type_id
      FROM TestTable
  ) id
  JOIN (
       SELECT COUNT(*) num, Test_type_id
         FROM TestTable
      GROUP BY Test_type_id  
  ) num ON id.Test_type_id <> num.Test_type_id
GROUP BY num.Test_type_id
```

The server's query plan for this is a little complex (maybe even a good curveball for testers to throw at new versions). But, it *materializes* each of those subqueries. That means it only need generate it once.